# Time series classification - ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, keras

I have to train a model to classify time-series data. There are 6 classes in this data, that is why I have encoded them with one-hot-encoder. The only input feature is the **"ecg"** column which consists of row vectors. The data looks like this;

```
                                               ecg      0  1  2  3  4  5
0    [[0.1912, 0.3597, 0.3597, 0.3597, 0.3597, 0.35...  1  0  0  0  0  0
1    [[0.2179, 0.4172, 0.4172, 0.4172, 0.4172, 0.41...  1  0  0  0  0  0
2    [[0.1986, 0.3537, 0.3537, 0.3537, 0.3537, 0.35...  0  1  0  0  0  0
3    [[0.2808, 0.5145, 0.5145, 0.5145, 0.5145, 0.51...  0  1  0  0  0  0
4    [[0.1758, 0.2977, 0.2977, 0.2977, 0.2977, 0.29...  0  0  1  0  0  0
5    [[0.2183, 0.396, 0.396, 0.396, 0.396, 0.396, 0...  0  0  1  0  0  0
6    [[0.204, 0.3869, 0.3869, 0.3869, 0.3869, 0.386...  0  0  0  1  0  0
7    [[0.1695, 0.2823, 0.2823, 0.2823, 0.2823, 0.28...  0  0  0  1  0  0
8    [[0.2005, 0.3575, 0.3575, 0.3575, 0.3575, 0.35...  0  0  0  0  1  0
9    [[0.1969, 0.344, 0.344, 0.344, 0.344, 0.344, 0...  0  0  0  0  1  0
10   [[0.2312, 0.4141, 0.4141, 0.4141, 0.4141, 0.41...  0  0  0  0  0  1
11   [[0.1862, 0.3084, 0.3084, 0.3084, 0.3084, 0.30...  0  0  0  0  0  1
12   [[0.2605, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.3814...  1  0  0  0  0  0
13   [[0.2154, 0.3733, 0.3733, 0.3733, 0.3733, 0.37...  1  0  0  0  0  0
.                            .                          .  .  .  .  .  .
.                            .                          .  .  .  .  .  .
.                            .                          .  .  .  .  .  .
.                            .                          .  .  .  .  .  .
```

First of all, I have sliced the dataframe to have my **train_x** and **train_y;**

```
train_x = final_dataset.iloc[:,0] #the only input feature is the first column
train_y = final_dataset.iloc[:,1:] # rest of the columns are class labels
```

After that, I have created my neural network and added layers in it;

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(256, input_shape = (1,))) # there is only one input feature
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
```

As you can see above, I have set the `input_shape` as 1, because there is only one input feature which is the `ecg` column. Actually, the confusing part is that part for me, because I can't choose the input shape since one row of the `ecg` column is a row vector which is shaped like this;

```
[[0.1912, 0.3597, 0.3597, 0.3597, 0.3597, 0.35... ]]
```

After all of that, I am starting to train my model;

```
adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)

model.compile(optimizer = adam, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_x,train_y,epochs = 500, batch_size = 32, validation_split = 0.3)
```

I have used the `categorical-crossentropy` as my loss function. When I run my code, I am having the following error;

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I am pretty new to Keras, so I couldn't figure it out what causes the problem and How can I fix it. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: @how long is the ecg signal ?

Comment: @mujjiga, it is different for each row

Comment: So your input size is not 1, the number of values in the ecg signal in one row will be your input size i.e len([0.1912, 0.3597, 0.3597, 0.3597, 0.3597, 0.35.....]).

Comment: For example, in the first row, the lenght of the ecg signal is 18937. At the second row, the lenght is 19039. It changes for each row.

Comment: If it varies then either you have to fix the length by chopping some part. But if you think chopping will effect the prediction then you have to use models like LSTM rather then fully connected NN.

Comment: @mujjiga, with chopping do you mean to reduce each row to the same lenght?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190715/discussion-between-mujjiga-and-ozan-yurtsever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mistake 1:** The input size is not 1, it is size of the ecg column (the size of the list containing ecg values per patient)

**Mistake 2:** Also you last dense layer is of size 3 which is wrong since you have 6 classes it should be 6.

Comment: Yes, I have forgotten to change it from 3 to 6. Yet, I couldn't understand what is the mistake 1. Can you be more clear? Thanks.